# CSS menu with plus

Tags: css

I'm with a problem with css sprites, I know the best way to do sprites but this way doesn't work with this menu I need to do.

CSS Code

```
/* SUB MENU
----------------------------------------------------------*/
div#sub-menu{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 211px;
    padding: 50px 0px 0px;
    z-index: 999;
}
div#sub-menu p{
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 0px 36px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
div#sub-menu ul li{
    height: 29px;
    margin: 2px 21px;
    border-bottom: 1px #353535 solid;
}
div#sub-menu ul li:first-child{
    border-top: 1px #353535 solid;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
div#sub-menu ul li:first-child a{
    margin: 2px 0px 3px;
}
div#sub-menu ul li a{
    display: list-item;
    width: 138px;
    height: 11px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px 15px;
}
div#sub-menu ul li a:hover{
    background: #f9c600;
    color: #fff;
}
```

HTML CODE

`<div id="sub-menu">
        <p>Produtos</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="arroz">arroz</a></li>
            <li><a href="azeite">azeite</a></li>
            <li><a href="especiarias">especiarias</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>`

I need the menu to have that final plus and still when we hover it be inside the a tag, i can give the sprite that i use if needed.

Can anyone help me on this please?

Final result needed:
[image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P3Nq5/)

Comment: Where in your CSS are you actually attempting to use a background sprite? As a followup: Why do you need a sprite to accomplish the design you show in your screenshot? It looks like you can accomplish that using straight up CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css3  `::after` so you can just add this

```
div#sub-menu ul li a::after{
    content:'+';
    color:#000;
    float:right;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:10px;
}

div#sub-menu ul li a:hover::after{
    color:#fff;
}
```

**DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/P3Nq5/4/**

Comment: I tried with :after and didn't work, what is the diference between :after and ::after? O.o

Comment: I think it's the same, so i tried with :after, it's works - http://jsfiddle.net/P3Nq5/8/

Comment: Weird because i tried that and it didn't show me nothing at all, maybe i did something that didn't let it to be show, well that a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the :after (or :before) pseudo class - http://jsfiddle.net/michaelburtonray/P3Nq5/2/

This was all I had to add:

```
div#sub-menu ul li a{
    position: relative;
}

div#sub-menu ul li a:after {
    content: "+";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.5em;
}
```

The "+" symbol is a common symbol so you don't need to use a sprite, but if you must can use both :before and :after together. This makes the markup a little longer.

http://jsfiddle.net/michaelburtonray/P3Nq5/7/

```
div#sub-menu ul li a{
    position: relative;
}
div#sub-menu ul li a:before,
div#sub-menu ul li a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.5em;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}

div#sub-menu ul li a:before {
    background: red;    
}
div#sub-menu ul li a:after {
    background: green;
    opacity: 0;
}


div#sub-menu ul li a:hover:before {
    opacity: 0;
}
div#sub-menu ul li a:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```